# WebRTC Certificate during DTLS

Tags: certificate, webrtc

We are trying to make more secure a WebRTC gateway. To ensure this, we decide to validate incoming WebRTC certificate via OCSP/CRL, but when we took a Wireshark capture, we realized that WebRTC using a self-signed certificate during DTLS as you can see from the link at below;

[WebRTC Self-Signed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5YXY.png)

Because of self-signed certificate, there is no way to use OCSP/CRL. So is there any way to import and use CA-signed certificate for WebRTC engine?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC has [generateCertificate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/generateCertificate) `static` function where you can specify the algorithm for signing certificates.

From the link above:

```
RTCPeerConnection.generateCertificate({
    name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
    hash: 'SHA-256',
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1])
}).then(function(cert) {
    var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({certificates: [cert]});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the code snippet seems to be creating and using our own certificates, not CA-signed. Is WebRTC self-signed certificate coming through DTLS after reading "{certificates: [cert]}" section? If this cert element in the array hits to the certificate stored in WebRTC keystore, it would be change to use our CA-signed certificate I think.

Comment: @korayguney, certificates are sent in DTLS connection. A certificate can also persist via IndexedDB